# Stored Procedure outputs empty results but query is successful

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I am very new to stored procedures with MYSQL.

If I run this code on my server

```
select * from groupover o
left join groupatt a on o.myindex = a.myindex and a.sessid = 20231
where o.univ = 'UofU';
```

I get my list of results successfully.

However when I transfer that select statement into a stored procedure where I am converting the sessid and university into variables it returns an empty result set.

I use the call command with the same information from above.
`call getgroups("20231","UofU");`

This is my Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`fsadmin`@`142.184.89.102` PROCEDURE `getgroups`(
    IN mysessid text(5),
    IN myuniv text(10),
)
BEGIN
    declare mywhere longtext;
    IF myuniv != "N/A" THEN
        set mywhere = concat("o.univ = ", myuniv);
        select * from groupover o
        left join groupatt a on o.myindex = a.myindex and a.sessid = mysessid
        where mywhere;
    END IF;
END
```

I am at a total loss and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where mywhere returns false..is there a reason why you  adopted this approach instead of just where o.univ = myuniv?

Comment: I am trying to ensure that in the future if the client needs to search on more than one university.  In that case the where condition would be o.univ = 'univ1' or o.univ = 'univ2'.
Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition:

```
where mywhere;
```

will not work as it makes the query be:

```
    select * from groupover o
    left join groupatt a on o.myindex = a.myindex and a.sessid = mysessid
    where 'o.univ = myuniv_parameter_value';
```

i.e, the condition becomes a plain string.

What you can do:

```
    select * from groupover o
    left join groupatt a on o.myindex = a.myindex and a.sessid = mysessid
    where o.univ = myuniv;
```

Alternatively use dynamic SQL (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`...)

Comment: Thank you, that absolutely fixes the problem.  I was trying to approach it like I would in PHP crafting the where string incase a future requirement is multiple universities in which case I would have looped through the universities to craft the where string.
I will look into dynamic SQL.  Thanks for you help